How should I handle tax that is less than my denominator?
Hello I am a new solidity dev. In this tax function I am dividing by the simplifed fraction ex(5% =1/20 so I am doing amount/tax rate). My question is since I am deploying on a network with low gas how can I tax the buys under 20 tokens because solidity doesn't do decimals so all buy's under 20 tokens will go untaxed. I want the initial supply to be realativly small so I dont want make it 100 billion tokens. And I also dont want to just charge 1 token in tax for all buys under 20 tokens cause if tokens takes off then a ton of the supply will be burned so most of the buys will be under 20 tokens and that wont work either.
Was wondering if anyone had a solution ?
uint taxAmt=amount/taxRate;
uint transferAmt=amount-taxAmt;
uint swapAmt=taxAmt/2;
uint tokenTaxAmt=taxAmt-swapAmt;
uint ethTaxAmt=swapTokensForETHAndSend(swapAmt,location);

_transfer(sender,recipient,transferAmt);
_transfer(sender,location,tokenTaxAmt);


One approach you could consider is to implement a tiered tax system. Instead of applying a flat tax rate to all transactions, you could have different tax rates for different transaction sizes.
For example, you could have a lower tax rate for transactions under 20 tokens and a higher tax rate for transactions over 20 tokens.
Here’s a simplified example of how you might implement this in Solidity:
function calculateTax(uint amount) internal returns (uint) {
    // Assuming token has 18 decimals (adjust according to the number of decimals)
    if (amount < 20e18) {
        // Apply lower tax rate for transactions under 20 tokens
        return amount * lowerTaxRate / 100; // Assuming lowerTaxRate is in percentage
    } else {
        // Apply higher tax rate for transactions over 20 tokens
        return amount * higherTaxRate / 100; // Assuming higherTaxRate is in percentage
    }
}

function buyTokens(uint amount) external {
    uint taxAmt = calculateTax(amount);
    uint transferAmt = amount - taxAmt;

    // Transfer tokens to recipient
    _transfer(sender, recipient, transferAmt);

    if (taxAmt > 0) {
        // Transfer taxed tokens to tax location
        _transfer(sender, taxLocation, taxAmt);
    }
}

In this example, lowerTaxRate and higherTaxRate are variables that you can adjust to set the tax rates for transactions under and over 20 tokens, respectively.
This way, you can still apply taxes to transactions under 20 tokens without needing to deal with decimals, and you have the flexibility to adjust tax rates as needed.
